# start and end dates for finding stock historical prices

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

Am trying to get the stock quotes for yahoo finance and print it on the console. However am having trouble with putting start and end dates. Here is the code that I have:

```
def get_quotes(ticker,start_date,end_date):
list = []

quote = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s={}&a=2&b=1&c=2011&d=10&e=30&f=2012&g=d'.format(ticker,start_date,end_date)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(quote) 
data = response.read()
string_data = data.decode(encoding='utf-8')
lines = string_data.splitlines()
for x in lines:
    data = [y for y in x.split(',')]
    list.append(data)
return list
```

For the quote section..how do you input start and end dates that are input by user? You can replace the '?s=' with {} to format but how would you do the same for dates?

Answer (score 1):

What you exactly want to do ?

Do you want to replace `2&b=1&c=2011&d` as begining date something like `29&b=10&c=2013&d` ?

**Updated code :**

A rough method to input start_date and end_date is below:

```
start_date = raw_input("Enter start date in form of D/M/Y: ").split("/")
end_date = raw_input("Enter end date in form of D/M/Y: ").split("/")
qoute = 'http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s={}&a=' + start_date[0] + '&b=' + start_date[1] + "&c=" + start_date[2] + '&d='+end_date[0] + '&e=' + end_date[1] + '&f=' + end_date[2] + '&g=d'
```

Comment: yes Nishant...that what am trying to do. Lets say the user inputs 2010-11-30..then 29&b=10&c=2013&d should be changed to the new input.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the dates from the user, use [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), i.e.

```
startDate = raw_input("Please enter the start date:")
```

For the formatting, if the user put in a 'nice' date, you can convert it to a [date](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#date-objects) object, and use [strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.date.strftime) to get the format you want

Comment: Thanks! I figured it.